# relation "admin_keywords" does not exist`

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to have scaffold actions for Keywords table as admin. This code begins to work after I restart the server and Remove `Admin::` from `/app/models/admin/keyword.rb`, then refresh website, get error and adding `Admin::` to model again. From that moment everything works fine. But after server Starts, I got this: (Rails 4)

`PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "admin_keywords" does not exist`

/app/controllers/admin/keywords_controller.rb source:

```
class Admin::KeywordsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @keywords = Admin::Keyword.all
  end
end
```

/app/models/admin/keyword.rb source:

```
class Admin::Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

going to url:

```
http://localhost:3000/admin/keywords
```

routes.rb:

```
  namespace :admin do
    resources :keywords
  end
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: Post your schema.rb (relevant part). Your keyword table should be named `admin_keywords`. You probably have named it as `keywords`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add namespace to your models, database table should contain this namespace too. For example model `Admin::Keyword` is related with `admin_keywords` table.

You can override model's table defining `self.table_name='your_table_name'` method in model.

```
class Admin::Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'your_table_name'
end
```